# What are the bonus for each defector mission?

Tags: heat-signature

I played a heat signature a bit and liberated and completed the defector missions of 2 stations. Defector #001 and #002. The first one allowed me to buy sidewinders, and the #002 said something about money.

What are the unlocks for each defector mission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missions themselves unlock the characters you play as, with their unique gear etc. For example, if you complete a defector mission and the defector starts with a gun and armour-piercing sword, he will become playable when you start with a new agent, along with his gear. They also have their own independent story missions.

The wiki is a little barren but incases it becomes more full you can find the reference here:

[Defectors - Heat signature wiki](https://heatsignature.gamepedia.com/Defectors)

Comment: What about the unlocks? Are they random on each galaxy?

Comment: I've only played on one campaign so I'm not sure if it's random, but there appears to be some structure to it (not a bunch of unlocks on one path etc)

I think the starting galaxies have less-power full gear you can unlock if you look the regions furthest you'll find they have better gear

Comment: I'm holding to accept this answer just to check if someone got a list of unlocks. If you edit it to add just tell me and I'll accept it. Otherwise, if this attracts no more answers, I'll accept

Comment: @Moacir I plan on making the list when I get home from work.

Comment: I'll wait for your update then :D

Comment: @Moacir - Hey man, sorry I didn't add any information on the defector mission unlocks. I'm not convinced all galaxies are the same so I didn't want to spend the time on it. I'm planning on doing a comparison when I reset my galaxy after finishing my first play through.